# Convert date to specific format in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to convert the current date to a format as follows in javascript:
Apr 12, 2011 06:42:03.

Any suggestions?????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+format+date

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566151/how-to-convert-date-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Little example I just whipped up for you.  Very easy to tell whats going on.

```
var monthNames = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

var today = new Date();
var cDate = today.getDate();
var cMonth = today.getMonth();
var cYear = today.getFullYear();

var cHour = today.getHours();
var cMin = today.getMinutes();
var cSec = today.getSeconds();

alert( monthNames[cMonth] + " " +cDate  + "," +cYear + " " +cHour+ ":" + cMin+ ":" +cSec );
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

```
dateFormat(now, "mmm dd, yyyy hh:MM:ss");
```

it is light weight (1.2 KB) and supports the following formats

- d     Day of the month as digits; no leading zero for single-digit days.
- dd    Day of the month as digits; leading zero for single-digit days.
- ddd   Day of the week as a three-letter abbreviation.
- dddd  Day of the week as its full name.
- m     Month as digits; no leading zero for single-digit months.
- mm    Month as digits; leading zero for single-digit months.
- mmm   Month as a three-letter abbreviation.
- mmmm  Month as its full name.
- yy    Year as last two digits; leading zero for years less than 10.
- yyyy  Year represented by four digits.
- h     Hours; no leading zero for single-digit hours (12-hour clock).
- hh    Hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (12-hour clock).
- H     Hours; no leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock).
- HH    Hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock).
- M     Minutes; no leading zero for single-digit minutes. Uppercase M unlike CF timeFormat's m to avoid conflict with months.
- MM    Minutes; leading zero for single-digit minutes. Uppercase MM unlike CF timeFormat's mm to avoid conflict with months.
- s     Seconds; no leading zero for single-digit seconds.
- ss    Seconds; leading zero for single-digit seconds.
- l or L    Milliseconds. l gives 3 digits. L gives 2 digits.
- t     Lowercase, single-character time marker string: a or p.
- tt    Lowercase, two-character time marker string: am or pm.
- T     Uppercase, single-character time marker string: A or P. Uppercase T unlike CF's t to allow for user-specified casing.
- TT    Uppercase, two-character time marker string: AM or PM. Uppercase TT unlike CF's tt to allow for user-specified casing.
- Z     US timezone abbreviation, e.g. EST or MDT. With non-US timezones or in the Opera browser, the GMT/UTC offset is returned, e.g. GMT-0500
- o     GMT/UTC timezone offset, e.g. -0500 or +0230.
- S     The date's ordinal suffix (st, nd, rd, or th). Works well with d.
- '…' or "…"    Literal character sequence. Surrounding quotes are removed.
- UTC:  Must be the first four characters of the mask. Converts the date from local time to UTC/GMT/Zulu time before applying the mask. The "UTC:" prefix is removed.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in http://www.datejs.com/

---

thanks for the comments guys, I should of really linked more directly to the formatting options.

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

Comment: That is for reading dates to a Date object, the questioner wants the opposite.

Comment: @Dykam: look properly before you comment.  DateJS also provides an extended [toString](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString) method which gives you [extensive control](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) over the date formatting.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry then. Last time I used it I didn't spot it then. Quite a while ago.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn & @Dykam for pointing that out, I've added more detail to mention a link to the formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://hacks.bluesmoon.info/strftime/) small library duplicates the `strftime()` functionality available in other languages in JavaScript.

Comment: FWIW, this is no longer maintained because it is now part of YUI.  There are some IE specific bugs too.  :(