# Convert text time values to valid date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, simpledateformat

```
var data = {
    "duration": {
        "value": 74384,
        "text": "20 hours 40 mins" //convert this to a valid time date format
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2137146,
        "text": "1,328 mi"
      },
}
```

Done few sample test:

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(data.duration.text));
var date = moment(new Date(data.duration.text));
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#UnitSystems

Comment: How exactly you think this would work ? Javascript date is time in milliseconds since 1.1.1970 if you want to make a new date from `20 hours 40 mins` the time will be `1.1.1970. 20 hours 40 mins` ...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 4):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Legs), the duration property has two attributes : 
`text` and `value`.

The value attribute returns the time in `seconds`. You can add in current time.

```js
var data = {
     "duration": {
     "value": 74384, //in seconds
     "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
   },
   "distance": {
     "value": 2137146,
     "text": "1,328 mi"
   },
};

var seconds = data.duration.value;//from value
var finalDateInMiliSeconds = new Date().getTime()+(seconds*1000);
console.log(new Date(finalDateInMiliSeconds));
```

Now, you can convert it any format you want. Refer [Convert date to specific format in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637576/convert-date-to-specific-format-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data= {
"duration": {
        "value": 74384,
        "text": "20 hours 40 mins" //convert this to a valid time date format
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2137146,
        "text": "1,328 mi"
      },
};

let date = new Date();
date = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate());
let whatYouWant = new Date(+date + data.duration.value*1000);
document.getElementById('time').innerText = whatYouWant;
```

```html
<span id='time'></span>
```

Comment: Do not put same answer again...Although improve other's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for time conversion.

```
function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}
```

[refrence of code is:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096367/how-to-convert-seconds-to-minutes-and-hours-in-javascript)